# Fitting a set of functions using same basis functions

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit the functions in the plot below, but I need them to be fitted using the same basis functions. I want to interpolate between the functions by interpolating between their coefficients, but I struggle finding a good fit for the upper functions. Apparently, polynomial fit doesn't work there.
Do you have a suggestion which basis functions to use or how to approach this problem differently?
[image: Plot of functions to be fitted]
This work is part of my research in sound synthesis using phase distortion. In this case I evaluated Sin with feedback phase modulation at different modulation indexes.

```
Module[{m, dx, x, i, p, w},
 m = Table[t, {t, 0.0, 1.2, 0.1}];
 dx = 0.001;
 phase = List[];
 waveform = List[];
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[m], i++,
  p = List[0.];
  w = List[0.];
  For[x = dx, x <= 4, x = x + dx,
   AppendTo[p, 2 Pi*x + m[[i]] Last[w]^2];
   AppendTo[w, Sin[Last[p]]]
   ];
  AppendTo[phase, p[[2001 ;; 2501]]/Pi - 4];
  AppendTo[waveform, w[[2001 ;; 3001]]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Resulting waveform at different modulation indexes]

To be able to implement this using phase distortion I need to model how the phasor coming into Sin changes with the modulation index. Since there is a symmetry between positive and negative phase I evaluated only a half of the phasor (as seen in the last graphic). The graphic in the beginning was basically f(x)-x to get rid of the linearity.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Why not interpolate between the functions directly? BTW, you will be more likely to get help if you supply a minimal working example (with code) that folks can paste into *Mathematica* and try out their ideas.

Comment: Hello, I tried to edit my post so it better illustrates my problem. I can't interpolate directly since I need to get an algorithm which can easily be implemented in environments like Native Instruments Reaktor, so i need to rely only on mathematical functions, not sampled data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Radial Basis Functions

One approach to interpolating data where it is difficult to model with an equation is to use radial basis functions as described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function).

For this example I propose using a simplified version where the distances are constant and applying the Nadaraya-Watson estimator.

[image]

Here the radial basis functions are gaussians about the known data points `xi` and values `yi`.

### Data

Starting with your phase data we will downsize it to 101 points for each `m` value. The `m` and `xin` values are the inputs and the `phase` is the output.

```
xin = Rescale[Range[501]];

data = Map[
   Transpose[{ConstantArray[Rescale[#, {1, 7}, {0, 1.2}], 101], 
      xin[[1 ;; 501 ;; 5]], phase[[#, 1 ;; 501 ;; 5]]}] &,
   Range[7]
   ];
```

This will produce a matrix dimensioned {7, 101, 3}. The innermost list represents

```
{m, xin, phase}
```

We want the data to be dimensioned {707, 3}.

```
data = Flatten[data, {{1, 2}, {3}}];
```

Now we create the input matrix, `Xmat` and the value vector, `yvec`.

```
Xmat = {data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]};
yvec = data[[All, 3]];
```

We set the number of data points to 707, the size of `yvec`.

```
Ndb = Length@yvec
```

### Define the radial basis functions

```
rdbFunction[Xvec_, dist_, Xmat_, Ndb_] := Module[
  (*
  Inputs:
    Xvec  - Input vector                  (nx x 1)
    dist  - distance between points
    Xmat  - Matrix of data base vectors   (nx x Ndb)
    Ndb   - Number of data base points
  *)

  (*
  Ouputs:
     rdb - radial basis function           (Ndb x 1)
  *)

  {
   rdb
   },

  rdb = Map[
    Exp[-Norm[Xvec - Xmat[[All, #]]]^2/(2*dist^2)] &,
    Range[Ndb]
    ];

  rdb = rdb/Total[rdb]
  ]
```

The euclidean distance between points is 0.01. By experimentation I found that cutting this in half worked well for this problem.

```
dist = 0.005;
```

Now we define the approximating function to be:

```
rdb[m_, x_]:=yvec.rdbFunction[{m, x}, dist, Xmat, Ndb]
```

### Test

We overlay the data (black) with a plot of the approximating function (red)

```
Show[
 Map[
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{indx, phase[[#]]}], 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}] &,
  Range[7]
  ],
 Map[
  Plot[rdb[Rescale[#, {1, 7}, {0, 1.2}], x, 0.5], {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}] &,
  Range[7]
  ],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly a very good fit.

### Interpolation

Now let's interpolate it. I'll show two cases

`m` = 0.7

```
Show[
 Map[
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{indx, phase[[#]]}], PlotStyle -> Black] &,
  Range[7]
  ],

 Plot[rdb[0.7, x, 0.5], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red],

 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and `m`=1.1

`Plot[rdb[1.1, x, 0.5]...`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The latter doesn't look right to the eye but if you do a numerical check you will find that it does in fact lie half way between the upper and lower known phase.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for posting your answer. This is a great approach and it really helps solve the problem. I didn't know this method before so I am glad I learned about it as I am sure I will find a chance to use it in the future as well.

Comment: Your `rdbFunction` can be shortened a bit: `rdbFunction[Xvec_, dist_, Xmat_, Ndb_] := Normalize[Table[Exp[-(Norm[Xvec - Xmat[[All, k]]]/dist)^2/2], {k, Ndb}], Total]`. As another note: the new `DistanceMatrix[]` function would be useful here (and for implementing RBFs in general).

Comment: @J.M. The shorter version was surprisingly slightly slower (8%). I was surprised because it doesn't use `Module` and took the ratio and then squared as opposed to squaring twice and then taking the ratio. However, using `DistanceMatrix` provided a 550% increase in speed (i.e., 5 1/2 times faster). `rdbFun[Xvec_, dist_, Xmat_, Ndb_] := Normalize[
  Exp[-1*(Flatten@DistanceMatrix[
        Transpose@Xmat,
        {Xvec}, DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance
        ])/(2 dist^2)
   ],
  Total]`